# empty backreference causes match failure in PHP... is there a workaround?

Tags: php, regex, backreference

I'm having trouble with a regular expression in PHP that uses a potentially empty backreference. I was hoping that it would work as explained in http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html:

> If a backreference was not used in a
>   particular match attempt (such as in
>   the first example where the question
>   mark made the first backreference
>   optional), it is simply empty. Using
>   an empty backreference in the regex is
>   perfectly fine. It will simply be
>   replaced with nothingness.

However it seems PHP is a bit different... from http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php:

> If a subpattern has not actually been
>   used in a particular match, then any
>   back references to it always fail.

As a simplified example, I want to match the following two things with this regex:

- {something} ... {/something}
- {something:else} ... {/something:else}

Where "something" is known ahead of time, and "else" can be anything (or nothing).

so I tried the following regex ("else" hardcoded for simplicity):

```
preg_match("/\{(something(:else)?)\}(.*?)\{\/something\\2\}/is", $data, $matches)
```

Unfortunately if (:else)? doesn't match, the \2 backreference fails.  If I make \2 optional (\2?), then I might match {something} ... {something:else}, which is no good.

Have I run into a limitation of regular expressions (the infamous "you need a parser, not a regex") or is this fixable?

Test program:

```
<?php
    $data = "{something} ... {/something}
             {something:else} ... {/something:else}
             {something:else} ... {/something}";

    // won't match {something} ... {/something}
    preg_match_all("/\{(something(:else)?)\}(.*?)\{\/something\\2\}/is", $data, $matches);
    print_r($matches);

    // change \\2 to \\2? and it matches too much
    preg_match_all("/\{(something(:else)?)\}(.*?)\{\/something\\2?\}/is", $data, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you simply use \1 instead of \2?

```
preg_match_all("/\{(something(:else)?)\}(.*?)\{\/\\1\}/is", $data, $matches);
```

as to "you need a parser" problem, you will / do need it to parse nested constructs.

Comment: both answers solved the problem, this one seemed "cleaner" to me.

Answer (score 2):

Well, why not replace the ? with an or?

Change

```
"/\{(something(:else)?)\}(.*?)\{\/something\\2\}/is"
```

To

```
"/\{(something(:else|))\}(.*?)\{\/something\\2\}/is"
```

That way the reference will always be captured, but it will sometimes be empty (which is ok)...

Comment: Aha! Knew I just needed another pair of eyes. It appears that will work.

Answer (score 0):

following class in constucted for such cases (like 
{something} ... {/something} or {something} ...   {something} ... {/something} {/something}
 and more. 
example with SL5_**preg_contentFinder** class

https://gist.github.com/sl5net/7029093#file-sl5_preg_contentfinder-php

```
        $content1 = $content = '`ha <!--[01.o0]-->1<!--[/01.o0]-->
```

hi [02.o0]2
ho  3
`';

```
            $pos_of_next_search = 0;
        $begin = '(<!--)?\[([^\]>]*\.o0)\](-->)?';
        $end = '<!--\[\/($2)\]-->';
        $cf = new SL5_preg_contentFinder($content);
        $cf->setBeginEnd_RegEx($begin, $end);
        $cf->setSearchMode('use_BackReference_IfExists_()$1${1}');
        $loopCount = 0;
        while ($loopCount++ < 5) {
            $cf->setPosOfNextSearch($pos_of_next_search);
            list($findPos['begin_begin'], $findPos['end_begin'],
                $findPos['begin_end'], $findPos['end_next'], $matchesReturn) = $cf->get_borders_left(__LINE__);
            $content = $cf->getContent();
            $expectedContent = $maxLoopCount;
            if ($maxLoopCount>3)$expectedContent = '';
            if ($content != $expectedContent)
                die(__LINE__ . 'ERROR :   $content != $expectedContent :' . " '$content'!= '$expectedContent ");
            if (is_null($findPos['begin_begin'])) {
                break;
            }
            echo(__LINE__ . ': '.$content1.' ==> "' . $content . '"');

            $pos_of_next_search = $findPos['end_next'];
        }
```